# MPI_File_open hangs on non-existent file

Tags: c, mpi

MPI is displaying irregular behavior when I call `MPI_File_open()` on a non-existing file. It just completely halts the entire application after the following example code

```
MPI_File testfile;
    char testfilename[FNAME_CHAR];
    sprintf(testfilename, "test.txt"); //non-existing file

    ierr = MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, testfilename, MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &testfile);
    if (ierr != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        printf("ierr: %d\n", ierr);
    }
    else {
        printf("opened %s\n", testfilename);
        MPI_File_close(&testfile);
    }
```

Normally should just work, as in the application should continue executing even if the file doesn't exists but it just completely hangs.

Comment: You can test first of the file exists. Although it doesn't fix any bugs of MPI, it allows you to continue. Use `if (access(testfilename,0)==0) //exists`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thanks this works, I'm on Windows so `_access` for VS or on Linux `#include <unistd.h>` for `access()`

Comment: As this is only a workaround, could you give some more details about OS and MPI implementation you use? As a user I would expect getting `MPI_ERR_NO_SUCH_FILE` in this example.

Comment: @ArturMalinowski you're right I would expect that too. OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and using `I_MPI` ifort 131, `icc --version` gives `14.0.2`